# Two columns as primary key OR one column as PK + index?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, primary-key, normalization

This table containg user's photos (thumbnails and full).
    Most of queries will have a "WHERE user_id = ?" condition.

```
CREATE TABLE photos (
  "photo_id" serial, -- serial is postgres' autoincrement
  "user_id" integer not null, -- foreign key to users table
  "filename_thumbnail_50" varchar not null,
  "filename_thumbnail_75" varchar not null, -- 75px x 75px thumbnail
  "filename_full" varchar not null,
  PRIMARY KEY ("photo_id", "user_id")
);
```

What's the best design and/or performance design for this usecase:
- Two columns primary key like the above example ?
- One primary key (photo_id) and an index on user_id ?

Comment: The two-column primary key you have doesn't really make any sense IMHO. Shouldn't it either be `(photo_id)` or `(user_id, filename)`?

Comment: sorry, I've updated my example, so it's a little bit more complex

Comment: For each row in a table, each column value should be dependent on "the key, the whole key, and nothing but the key." "Dependent on" means that "the correct value is identified by..." Adding `user_id` to the serial column breaks the second part; your table would not be in 2nd normal form, and would be subject to the related anomalies. See any book or article on relational database normalization.

Comment: A key is a minimal superkey - a set of attributes which are supposed to be irreducibly unique. A uniqueness constraint is what enforces that rule. From your question it seems like either you don't understand your requirements (is photo_id itself intended to be unique or not?) or you don't understand keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The primary key should follow your *business rules* and nothing else. As a photo as such does not have a "real" (i.e. natural) primary key, using a serial as the PK absolutely makes sense.

Extending the primary key with `user_id` does not make any sense and does not serve any purpose (as the `photo_id` will be unique anyway, you only add overhead to the index maintainence). And with the `user_id` being the second column in the index it is very unlikely it will be used for a query that limits on `user_id` (not impossible but unlikely)

So I would go stick with the PK on `photo_id` and add an index on `user_id` (it's always a good idea to index foreign key columns anyway).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I should learn more about indexes.

Comment: @younes0: I can highly recommend this site: http://use-the-index-luke.com it is really very good in explaining how indexes work.

Answer (score 2):

The primary key as written is not useable for searching by user_id, since user_id is the second column in the key.

Your second option is best - a primary key on the photo_id only, since this is the unique identifier for the record, and add a separate index on user_id for your queries.

Answer (score 1):

In cases where you have a column specifically for identification purposes (in this case photo_id) there should be no need to have a 2nd key column.

If your situation could have multiple records with the same photo_id and different user_ids then I think it would be better to have a middle table to create a many-to-many relationship and keep the single primary key.  For example:

```
CREATE TABLE photos (
  "photo_id" serial, 
  -- other columns
  PRIMARY KEY ("photo_id")
);

CREATE TABLE users (
  "user_id" serial, 
  -- other columns
  PRIMARY KEY ("user_id")
);

CREATE TABLE photos_users (
  "photo_user_id" serial, 
  "photo_id" integer, -- not sure if this datatype is correct for postgres
  "user_id" integer, -- not sure if this datatype is correct for postgres
  PRIMARY KEY ("photo_user_id")
);
```

As far as I am aware - a 2nd key column is needed where there is no specific id column for the table in question and there could be duplication if only 1 key is used.  An example of this is below:

```
CREATE TABLE Person (
    "FirstName" varchar NOT NULL,
    "LastName" varchar NOT NULL,
    "PostalCode" varchar NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("FirstName", "LastName", "PostalCode")
);
```

In the above case `FirstName` would not be unique enough to have as a primary key, nor would `FirstName` and `LastName`, so in this case at least 3 columns would be used.  Of course it would be better to have an `ID` or `PersonID` column and use that as the primary key.

As far as performance is concerned primary keys do not make much of an impact.  Worry about indexes.  Make sure that any column that will be used in a `WHERE` clause or `JOIN` or `AGGREGATE` has an index.

Answer (score 0):

If you have aoutoincremented ID, I don't think that more then you need user_id as primary key. Why don't you use forign key on user_id to your user table (I giess you have one)?